# NSURLResponse not showing location in header

Tags: ios

It looks like `NSURLResponse` is trimming the location out of the response header I'm getting back.  If I run a curl command, I get:

```
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Mon, 18 Mar 2013 14:43:41 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.14 ZendServer/5.0
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=kv1j4cjpt69q91sgd2m270d775; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< Location: http://kt-act.s3.amazonaws.com/...
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html
```

However, hitting the same endpoint with the following Obj-C code:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/content",kBaseAPIURL,_document.href]]];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
[_resourceData setLength:0];
_progressView.progress=0.0f;
_loadingView.hidden=NO;
fileSize = [[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[response expectedContentLength]] intValue];
NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
NSDictionary *headers = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields];
NSLog(@"Response: %@", headers);
}
```

Gives me this:

```
2013-03-18 10:40:11.537 KTMobile[25221:1ac03] Response: {
"Cache-Control" = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
Connection = close;
"Content-Length" = 36;
"Content-Type" = "application/json";
Date = "Mon, 18 Mar 2013 14:38:44 GMT";
Expires = "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT";
Pragma = "no-cache";
Server = "Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)";
"Www-Authenticate" = "Basic realm=\"Protected\"";
"X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.3.14 ZendServer/5.0";
"X-Response-Time" = "0.153447";
}
```

Does anyone know why it's losing the location header? And why curl reports a text/html but NSURLResponse reports an application/json return? I've also tried to get the query/params part of the response URL as suggested in another SO thread, but that still doesn't give me the location.

EDIT:
I have also tried the `connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse` delegate.

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse
{
NSLog(@"Redirect response url! %@", [redirectResponse URL]);
NSLog(@"Redirect response! %@", redirectResponse);

return request;
}
```

This returns both null for both `[redirectResponse URL]` and `redirectResponse` object. It's as if the server endpoint is simply not returning a location object for the obj-c code. Is there any reasoning for this behavior?

Comment: Is the `Location` header the same as the URL property of the request or the response?

Comment: Unfortunately the URL property of the response location is the original request URL!

Answer (score 0):

"HTTP 302" is a redirect response, and the "Location" header gives the new URL from where the resource should be loaded.

`NSURLConnection` follows the redirection transparently, and the `NSURLResponse` is the response for the redirected request.

I think you can implement `connection:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:` if you want to be informed about redirections, but I have never actually tried this.

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried this as well. I'll edit my original question with the code I've done for this. redirectResponse, for whatever reason, is null in my case. Is there any reason that the response I'm getting with iOS could be different from a curl?

Comment: @LyricalPanda: I don't know :-) *I* would try to use a network monitor (e.g. Wireshark), trace the request and response packets and look for differences.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction - turned out it was a 401 error that I wasn't able to easily see with the `[response allHeaderFields]`. Had to run Charles and look at the response through there to actually see it. Thanks for the suggestion @Martin!